# How to make my InfiniteLoopingList class implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

I am making a prototype application and for that I designed a class that behaves like an infinite looping list. That is, if my internal list contains 100 values, when I ask for the 101st value, I get the first, the 102nd yields the second, and so on, repeating.

So I would like to write the following code:

```
var slice = loopingListInstance.Skip(123).Take(5);
```

And for that I need to implement IEnumerable suitable, as I understand.

Here is my current code:

```
public class InfiniteLoopingList : IEnumerable<double>
{
    double[] _values = File.ReadLines(@"c:\file.txt")
                            .Select(s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                            .ToArray();
    int _size;

    public InfiniteLoopingList()
    {
        _size = _values.Length;
    }

    public double this[int i]
    {
        get { return _values[i % _size]; }
        set { _values[i % _size] = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<double> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // ???? now what ?? :(
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you implemented the indexer property, you could do it via the simplest way as follows:

```
public IEnumerator<double> GetEnumerator()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
        yield return this[i++];
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

**EDIT**
Please notice, that this is not really infinite loop. This approach will only work until `i = int.MaxValue`. Thanks to @oleksii.

Comment: This seems like what I needed. Gonna test it after lunch and come back to post some feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @oleksii Yup, you are right, it's not a really infinite loop. But I doubt somebody really needs an infinite sequence. I've updated the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a class for this...

An extension method will do the trick:

```
public static class InfEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> LoopForever<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src)
    {
        var data = new List<T>();
        foreach(var item in src)
        {
            data.Add(item);
            yield return item;
        }

        for(;;)
        {
            foreach(var item in data)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can take a sequence and make it a looping, infinite sequence:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> mySeq = ...;
IEnumerable<Foo> infMySeq = mySeq.LoopForver();
IEnumerable<Foo> aSelectionOfInfMySeq = infMySeq.Skip(101).Take(5);
```

Comment: So how would this help me on using this: `var slice = loopingListInstance.Skip(123).Take(5);`?

Comment: Instead of the `ToList`, you might do `src.GetEnumerator` and do `Reset` after each loop.

Comment: @Alex No. .ToList was explicitly chosen, because IEnumerable makes no guarantee about repeated enumerations of the source.

Comment: ...although I've modified slightly so that we don't have to greedily consume the entire source sequence.

Comment: @oleksii Yes, if the source itself is infinite, you will get an OOME (if you try to consume the infinite sequence). This code is written to take a ***finite*** sequence and make it infinite which is what OP wants. Still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the IEnumerator interface:

```
class InifniteEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T> {        
    private int index = -1;
    private IList<T> innerList;
    private int repeatPos;
    public InifniteEnumerator(IList<T> innerList, int repeatPos) {
        this.innerList = innerList;
        this.repeatPos = repeatPos;
    }
    public T Current {
        get {
            if (index == -1) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            return this.innerList[index];
        }
    }
    object IEnumerator.Current {
        get {
            return this.Current;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose() {

    }
    public bool MoveNext() {
        this.index++;
        if (this.index == repeatPos) {
            this.index = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void Reset() {
        this.index = -1;
    }
}
```

and then return an instance of it in the GetEnumerator methods:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() {
    return new InifniteEnumerator(this, 100);
}
```